# jquery preload images flickering on rollover

Tags: jquery

I flat out copied this little jquery preloader [probably from an answer here]

It was working just fine, now however:

- the images will flicker from the normal state to blank to the state on mouse over AND on mouse out the first time a mouse goes over and out
- subsequent mouse overs work fine.
- in the network inspector, I can see they are loading with the page BUT on mouseover they will get loaded again. The entry looks like:

  image.jpg GET 200 image/jpeg jquery.min.js

Here is the preload script and the rollover script as well:

```
// preloading
var loadimages = [];

$('.preload-image').each(function(i){
    loadimages[i] = $(this).attr('src');
})

$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
       $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}

$([loadimages]).preload();
// preloading


// category tile rollovers
$( ".category-cell-link" )
    .mouseover(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var rollover = '/Assets/Images/shopbybike/' + id + '-over.jpg';
        var style = 'background:transparent url(' + rollover + ')no-repeat 0 0;'
        $(this).attr("style", style);
        })
    .mouseout(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var rollout = '/Assets/Images/shopbybike/' + id + '.jpg';
        var style = 'background:transparent url(' + rollout + ')no-repeat 0 0;'
        $(this).attr("style", style);
    });
```

this did work without the flicker effect, but I didn't change any code after it was working.

Not sure why this is happening, can anyone see what I am missing/doing wrong?

Live example: [woodcraft](http://www.woodcraft-cfm.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?display=action&emptyoverride=yes&template=Assets/XHTML/ShopByBikeCategories.html)

Comment: I don't have the time to debug your page to see what you actually try to do. But  `$('<img/>')[0].src = this;` is pretty useless. It on the one hand triggers the loading of the image, but it will not keep the element in memory, as the image that is created here can be released by the GC right after it was created. As of that the _"preloaded"_ image might be not in memory anymore when it is finally used.

Comment: Thanks, not keeping the image in memory provided a clue to move the loading script to last - seems to work. A more helpful answer would have been to point out ~how~ to correctly keep an image in memory [and what a 'GC' is]

Comment: GC = garbage collector (taking care to release not used resources). Moving it to the end might just obscure the problem. IMHO you need to store the created images in a list so that it won't be released by the GC. Oddly enough the examples I find here on SO don't do that, so I first want to revalidate my statement before posting it as answer. (Do you have caching disabled while testing, because then it would be definitely the problem of the flickering)?